# Print PDFs automatically with python

Tags: python, pdf, printing

I am building a website which accepts pdf from users and the options, like pages to print, copies, color or black&white and the shop from which they want to get it printed.

The pdf will be stored in server and will be passed on to the shop to print. How do i get it printed automatically with those options applied. One way i thought was to edit the pdf and sent to the store to print with the options applied.

How do i print the pdf automatically and report back to the server that the pdf was printed?

chose python as it may have easy implementation.
BTW i'll build website using NodeJS

Comment: Not enough information to go off of. What I get is that you have pdf's that get stored to a server and passed to a ship to print, I am confused by what you mean by have print automatically applied? Do you have any sample code?

Comment: the pdf will be sent to the shop, which should be printed automatically(nobody has to ctrl+p). lets say the pdf gets stored on the computer of the shop. Now how to print it automatically?

Comment: If more information is required, please let me know. Thankyou

Comment: Thankyou so much!!!! Exactly what I needed. Will learn to use .pcl files ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
import os

os.startfile("C:/Users/TestFile.txt", "print")
```

This will start the file, in its default opener, with the verb 'print', which will print to your default printer.Only requires the os module which comes with the standard library

This only works on windows. So if you want it to work on other OS's you'll need a way to detect which OS the pdf is being sent to.

Comment: ok. Thankyou. it solves part of my problem and i think i can work out the rest from here.

Comment: let me know if you need anymore help